# Anyone have a skeletonizer library or psuedo code

Tags: java, graphics

I am already using the SkeletonFilter from jhlabs.com but it has a few issues. For example it seems to remove small details that are perpedicular to the longer line. An example is the serifs from a capital A when skeletonized are removed.

I have looked at some tracers such as Autotracer and potrace but they do slightly more than just plain skeletonization.

Are there any other java alternatives ?

Comment: Could you give some context regarding skeletonization? What is it?